# To Unequal two list when defined equal before

Tags: java, arrays, list, arraylist

```
ArrayList<Integer> list1= new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<Integer> list2= new ArrayList<>();
for(int i=1;i<=5;i++){
list1.add(i);
}
System.out.println("List1 "+list1);
list2=list1;
System.out.println("List2 "+list2 );
list2.add(6);
System.out.println("List1 Changed "+list1 );
```

Output :

```
List1 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
List2 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
List1 Changed [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

I know on using list2=list1, and on changing list2, list1 also will get altered. But I dont want my list1 to get it changed. I have to use list2=list1, but is there any way I get the List1 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] only ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is Java "pass-by-reference" or "pass-by-value"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value)

Comment: assign a clone of `list1` into `list2` instead.

Comment: @JeroenSteenbeeke: Nothing is being passed to any methods here.

Comment: @Thilo indeed, but a reference is being changed, so I thought it might be helpful in explaining the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want `list2` to reference a different `List` than `list1`, make a copy:

Change

```
list2=list1;
```

to

```
list2 = new ArrayList<>(list1);
```

Note that since you are overwriting the reference to the original `List` referenced by `list2`, there's no need to create it in the first place:

```
ArrayList<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
for(int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    list1.add(i);
}
System.out.println("List1 "+list1);
ArrayList<Integer> list2 = new ArrayList<>(list1);
System.out.println("List2 "+list2);
list2.add(6);
System.out.println("List1 Not Changed "+list1);
```

Comment: There is a method to do the same instead of creating new Object.

Comment: @ꜱᴜʀᴇꜱʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ yes there is, but that statement is also meant to replace the `ArrayList<Integer> list2= new ArrayList<>();` statement.

Answer (score 1):

```
list2=list1;
```

You are overriding list2 with `list1` reference. If you want to keep them separate, just add them and don't assign

```
list2.addAll(list1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can copy the list instead of just assigning a reference to it:

```
list2 = new ArrayList<>(list1);
```

Answer (score 0):

`list1` and `list2` are variables that are both a reference to an object  which is of type `ArrayList<Integer>`. They have exactly the same value after `list2 = list1` is executed, this value is an address of an object, NOT the object itself. This means that at the point you lost the original list that `list2` was pointing to and you have two variables pointing to the same place in the memory.

What you can do to keep two independent lists is add elements from `list1` to `list2`, like this

```
List<Integer> list2 = new ArrayList<>(list1);
```

or this:

```
List<Integer> list2 = new ArrayList<>();
/*code inbetween*/
list2.addAll(list1);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    ArrayList<Integer> list1= new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Integer> list2= new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i=1;i<=5;i++){
    list1.add(i);
    }
    System.out.println("List1 "+list1);
    list2=(ArrayList<Integer>) list1.clone();
    System.out.println("List2 "+list2 );
    list2.add(6);
    System.out.println("List1 Changed "+list1 );
```